# How do you figure out why a drive is dropping out on a Marvell Raid Controller?

Tags: raid, sata

I just got a Marvell SATA Raid controller for my Dell T-410 (the existing Raid card was full 0+1); trying to use it with 2 drives in Raid-1, but one of the drives keeps falling out.

The log shows nothing... is there any way to figure out why the WD Red 3TB drive is falling out of the array?

Steps I did:

1. I moved the drives to ports 0/1.
2. Created the array using `create -o vd -d 0,1 -r1 -n "Slow"`
3. In the browser, it indicates that everything is good (2 drives, both good)
4. Initialized (GPT) and Quick-Formatted the volume (Drive J).

At the end of format, the 2nd drive is "offline", yet the status log says nothing. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdRIC.png)

I put the disks into a Raid 0 configuration, and it works (but I want slow-redundancy for these -- think "Attic Storage")... anyone have any ideas?

More testing:

1. I swapped SATA drives.  The Port1 still dropped.
2. I swapped SATA cables (switch 0 & 1).  Port 1 still dropped.
3. I swapped Power cables (switch 0 & 1). Survived HDTune (write speed = 1 MB/s?!).  After formatting, Port 1 still dropped (write speed went up to normal now).

Is this card worthless?

Comment: Ick.  Moved the repro steps and screenshot to the question.  I keep forgetting how serverfault works.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that you have some defective hardware?